# Find Strongly Connected Graph such that the difference between the maximum and minimum edges is minimum

Tags: algorithm, graph, directed-graph, weighted-graph, strongly-connected-graph

Given a **Directed Weighted Graph** which is **Strongly Connected**. I need to find a **strongly connected sub-graph** out of this graph such that the ***difference between the maximum and minimum weight edges*** is **minimum**.

To be more clearly, I need to **get rid of edges** in such a way that after removing them, the graph will **still be strongly connected** and the ***difference between the maximum and minimum weight edges*** is **minimum**.

**Here is an example:**

The first line is the number of N nodes and M edges of this graph. The next M lines represent the edges of this graph.

```
3 6

1 2 8

2 3 32

3 1 16

1 3 81

3 2 243

2 1 27
```

The chosen N-nodes sub-graph would contain the edges:

```
1 2 8

2 3 32

3 1 16
```

The difference between the maximum and minimum weight edges is: 32 - 8 = 24.
Which is minimum among all choices.

I'm looking for an optimal solution. There are at most *3000* nodes and *5000* edges.

Comment: What does "*the difference between the maximum and minimum edges is minimum*" mean?  What is a maximum and/or minimum edge in a subgraph? I cannot find anything in the literature that use the terms like this.  "Maximum/minimum path" yes, but not min/max edge.

Comment: @RBarryYoung: The edges are weighted, so any given subgraph has a minimum- and maximum-weight edge. Subtract the former from the latter to get the cost of this subgraph.

Comment: Why is my post still closed? Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why is this question sill closed? Can anyone tell me what add?

Comment: I don't understand, what do I have to do to reopen the question? It is clear, it has an example and even an accepted answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an algorithm that tests whether a given digraph G = (V, E) is strongly connected in O(f(|V|, |E|)) time, this problem can be solved in time O(|E|*f(|V|, |E|)) -- and better than that if testing for strong connectivity can be done more quickly after adding or removing a single edge to an already-tested digraph.

Sort edges in increasing order by weight, and number them in this order. Initially, add the first (lowest-weight) edge to the set E' of selected edges; for as long E' is not strongly connected, add the next edge to it. If this loop does not terminate then G is not strongly connected. Otherwise, when it stops, after adding, say, edge j, we have found a minimum-difference solution *given that we include edge 1*. Record this (1, j) solution as the incumbent.

Now remove edge 1 from E', so that edge 2 is the lowest-weight edge remaining in E'. Leave all other already-decided edges in place, and begin adding the next-lowest-weight edges again, starting at edge j+1, until an SCG forms. This can be repeated to compute the minimum-difference solution *given that the lowest-weight edge included is edge i*, for each i <= |V|. Keep the best overall.

Note that when solving for the starting point i+1, it isn't necessary to get rid of the edges decided for the previous starting point i: If edges i, i+1, ..., j-1 do not form an SCG, then edges i+1, i+2, ..., j-1 do not form an SCG either. Exploiting this means the overall outer loop runs just |E| times, instead of O(|E|^2) times.